# Integrate interactive map on Java application

Tags: java, maps

Good evening,
I've a file with many GPS tracks (a series of [Latitude,Logitude] points, approximately 130000), and I would display these on a Google Maps like map.

I shall start that I'm not an expert and this is my first attempt to create an application like this.

I've searched for informations and I found the Google Static Map API. The cons is that the HTTP request is limited to 2048 char, so it is too short for my purpose.

Any ideas?

Comment: Or some money ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the paid enterprise/premium package.

This will let you bypass the normal free restrictions, and give you a bunch of extra features.

Details on the enterprise API:
https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en/maps/products/mapsapi.html

Take a look at the pricing page as well:
https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en/maps/pricing/

More helpful info on rates and limits with the premium plan:
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits